# Expresso Store: The number parameter is required

Tags: expresso-store, paypal

I'm using Payflow Pro with Paypal and I'm running into a bit of an issue. My local test server does not have an SSL setup. With that in mind, if I enter the test credit card details on the final page I can make a successful connection with the gateway and have a completed purchase. If I enter the test credit card details on a step which is before my final confirmation page, I get an error of "The number parameter is required" when I make my final purchase.

- Is this a bug?
- Do credit card details need to be submitted on the    last step?
- Or, is this due to the lack of SSL in my local test    environment?
- Maybe it's another issue all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's due to the lack of SSL. Store 2 allows test credit card details to be submitted without having SSL enabled on your server (although you should do it anyway, for consistency between your development and production environments).

> Do credit card details need to be submitted on the last step?

Yes. With Store, payment details must always be submitted on the last step of the checkout. This is because not all gateways support separate authorize/capture operations, so we must immediately charge the supplied credit card. It would be unwise to charge the credit card without also marking the order as complete.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for the confirmation!